# Hyper-V listed on Win 2012 but not Win 8.1 Pro (same machine)

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I bought an Acer laptop, and installed Windows Server 2012 to do some web site testing for a client.  On that installation, I used Server Manager to install Hyper-V, and two further installations on Win2012 running as VM's.  Everything worked perfectly.

Once the testing was done, I cleared the hard drive and installed Windows 8.1 Pro.  Hoping that I could bring my VM's onto Windows 8.1 if required, I tried to install Hyper-V on 8.1 Pro, but, it does not show in the Add Features list.

I checked with Acer customer support, who say the laptop isn't designed for virtualization, and that's why Windows 8.1 won't show the option.  If so, why did it work perfectly in Windows 2012?  There is no BIOS option to enable virtualization.

Can anyone explain why 2012 would allow Hyper-V, but not 8.1 Pro on the **same machine**?!  Here's a CPU-Z grab showing the technology in the laptop, if that helps.

[image]

Securable also shows virtualization is supported:

[image]

Comment: You are 100% positive your running `Windows 8.1 Professional`?

Comment: I am certain that windows feature will be available, and installable on retail Windows Pro 8.1 system even if the virtualization features are disabled in the BIOS.  It just won't let you start VMs unless the BIOS feature is enabled.

Comment: FINALLY figured it out.  The install media *is* Win 8.1 Pro, but, it was pulling in the OEM license key from EUFI and dropping back to 8.1 standard at install.  I never realised until I checked in System and saw no "Pro" listed.  I followed this useful guide (http://bit.ly/1EQinwq) and re-installed with the PID.txt file, and now I see Hyper-V.  Thanks for your *"100% positive"* comment; I never would have double-checked otherwise!